# como puedo lograr este effecto con sass/scc y htlm

Tags: css, scss, frontend

como dice arriba realmente soy nuevo en el mundo del frontend y estoy haciendo una navbar con boostrap y vuejs tengo un sidenav y quisiera que cuando el rooter le ponga la clase active al elemento del nav se vea como en la foto seria de gran ayuda si me dijeran como puedo lograr este efecto gracias
es el como cuadrito blanco que se ve al lado del elemnto .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pues logra hacerlo de manera sencilla usando el pseudo elemento before aplicando la posicion absoluta y luego la  relative a el a element :D

Answer (score 1):

Pues esto lo podrias lograr de diferentes maneras:

- Dibujandolo con `CSS`
- Usando un `SVG` (recomendacion personal)
- Usando un `PNG`

Cada elemento `html` de tu `sidenav` debe tener esta imagen o icono ya incrustada, pero le aplicarias la propiedad `display: none` para que no se vea, pero que siga reservando el espacio en el navegador para ese elemento y entonces mostrarlo.

Lo quebes hacer es crear una funcion que cambie la propiedad display de ese elemento y de esa forma, validar si un elemento tiene la clase active, de ser asi, en tu `svg` la propiedad `display` cambiaria de `display: hidden` a `display: block`

Comment: Cómo podría dibujarlo con css ?

Comment: Si vuelves a poner la foto podria ayudarte, que no recuerdo bien como se veia